# Django- Nginx and Gunicorn timeout on POST request

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I'm setting up an Ubuntu EC2 instance by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file) droplet tutorial. Everything seems to be working fine on my local development machine but I am getting timeout errors(502,504) on my EC2 instance.

I checked my gunicorn logs and there was a [CRITICAL] WORKED TIMEOUT message so I increased the "timeout" parameter for gunicorn to 300 and set the proxy_connect_timeout to 75s and proxy_read_timeout to 300s on my site's nginx config even though the process should have taken much less time than that. I think the error is not with the process taking the time but some misconfiguration in my nginx or gunicorn config.

GET requests that retrieve data from the DB seem to be working fine but POST requests that write to the DB don't seem to work.

Here are my config and log files

Gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/standalone_ntp_backend.sock standalone_ntp_backend.wsgi:application --timeout 300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
       # include proxy_params;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/standalone_ntp_backend.sock;
    }
    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2019/06/14 12:10:40 [error] 1062#1062: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 110.44.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /core/create-trip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/standalone_ntp_backend.sock/core/create-trip", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/core/create-trip"
2019/06/14 12:10:58 [error] 1062#1062: *7 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 110.44.xx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /core/create-trip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/standalone_ntp_backend.sock:/core/create-trip", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/core/create-trip"
2019/06/14 12:26:32 [error] 1062#1062: *9 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 110.44.xx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /core/rest-auth/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/standalone_ntp_backend.sock/core/rest-auth/password/reset/", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/core/rest-auth/password/reset/"
```

Gunicorn debug log

```
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2229] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: None
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:8000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 1
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 30
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 1000
  group: 1000
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: DEBUG
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: standalone_ntp_backend.wsgi:application
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f50e62bbf28>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f50e62cd0d0>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f50e62cd1e0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f50e62cd2f0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f50e62cd400>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f50e62cd510>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f50e62cd620>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f50e62cd730>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f50e62cd840>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f50e62cd950>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f50e62cd9d8>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f50e62cdae8>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f50e62cdbf8>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f50e62cdd08>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f50e62cde18>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2229] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2229] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2229] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (2229)
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2229] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2232] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2232
[2019-06-14 12:53:38 +0000] [2229] [DEBUG] 1 workers
```

api_views.py

```
class CreateTripView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        print("INSIDE GET")
        return Response("Hi from GET")

    def post(self, request):
        print("INSIDE POST")
        #logic here(serializer validation and save)
        return Response(data)
```

I've added those print statements above so that it might help with the following systemctl gunicorn log:

```
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 12:57:23 +0000] [2367] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 12:57:23 +0000] [2367] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/standalone_ntp_backend.sock (2367)
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 12:57:23 +0000] [2367] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 12:57:23 +0000] [2385] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2385
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 12:57:23 +0000] [2387] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2387
Jun 14 12:57:23 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 12:57:23 +0000] [2388] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2388
Jun 14 12:57:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: Loading : /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/.env
Jun 14 12:57:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information
Jun 14 12:57:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: Loading : /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/.env
Jun 14 12:57:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information
Jun 14 12:57:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: Loading : /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/.env
Jun 14 12:57:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information
Jun 14 12:57:36 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]:  - - [14/Jun/2019:12:57:36 +0000] "GET /core/view-trip/10 HTTP/1.0" 200 15811 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36"
Jun 14 12:57:42 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: INSIDE GET
Jun 14 12:57:42 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]:  - - [14/Jun/2019:12:57:42 +0000] "GET /core/create-trip HTTP/1.0" 200 7204 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36"
Jun 14 12:59:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]:  - - [14/Jun/2019:12:59:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 74 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nimbostratus-Bot/v1.3.2; http://cloudsystemnetworks.com)"
Jun 14 13:02:50 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:02:50 +0000] [2367] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2387)
Jun 14 13:02:50 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:02:50 +0000] [2387] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2387)
Jun 14 13:02:50 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: INSIDE POST
Jun 14 13:02:51 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:02:51 +0000] [2402] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2402
Jun 14 13:02:51 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: Loading : /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/.env
Jun 14 13:02:51 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information
Jun 14 13:03:24 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]:  - - [14/Jun/2019:13:03:24 +0000] "GET /core/rest-auth/password/reset/ HTTP/1.0" 405 7744 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safa
Jun 14 13:07:48 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:07:48 +0000] [2367] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2385)
Jun 14 13:07:48 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:07:48 +0000] [2385] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2385)
Jun 14 13:07:48 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: INSIDE POST
Jun 14 13:07:48 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:07:48 +0000] [2409] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2409
Jun 14 13:07:48 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: Loading : /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/.env
Jun 14 13:07:48 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information
Jun 14 13:08:32 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:08:32 +0000] [2367] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2402)
Jun 14 13:08:32 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:08:32 +0000] [2402] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2402)
Jun 14 13:08:32 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: [2019-06-14 13:08:32 +0000] [2411] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2411
Jun 14 13:08:33 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: Loading : /home/ubuntu/standalone_ntp_backend/.env
Jun 14 13:08:33 ip-172-31-41-70 gunicorn[2367]: The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information
```

When I send a POST request(json) to myendpoint /create-trip, I get 504 Gateway Time-out(gunicorn logs above) but GET request to my /view-trip/trip_id endpoint which retrieves values from the database seems to be working just fine.

How do I configure Nginx and Gunicorn to fix these timeout issues? Thanks.

edit: It seems the 'print("Inside POST")' in api_viewsets.py executes only after I see the 504- Gateway timeout.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the nginx or gunicorn? If you will execute logic in your Post request section (in a shell, for ex.), will it work as you planned or will it cause DB table lock or smth similar? If it is, there is no point in increasing timeout param.

Comment: In order to try out the logic of the function int the shell, I need to mock the "request" of DRF. However, I did not find any way to mock DRF's implementation of request. I could only mock <WSGI-request object> using rest_framework.test.RequestFactory.

Is there any way I can test this on the shell or mock the request object from DRF? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not install RabbitMQ in the production server and that was causing all the issues. It's fixed now.